# Is there a grails way to cache grails domain objects with a timeout

Tags: caching, grails, grails3

For tables which will never change for the rest of eternity, you can add this to a domain class:

```
static mapping = {
    cache true
}
```

However, in real life, this is next to useless as all table change, even if its slowly. E.g. we have a currency and country table. We read it with every request.

It is possible we add or remove currencies (e.g. if we no longer support them), or modify a country, but this may happen once a month or even a year.  However, when it is modified, the new version HAS to be picked up with server restarts.

I.e. the cache has to have some sort of timeout, so it can refresh.

Is there any plugin or solution to this for grails 3?

Maybe a job which kicks off every hour, and some how gets the caches to re-read?

Grails 3.3.8 (grails 4 is not an option currently)

Answer (score 0):

Knowing more about the app might affect the recommendation but a simple approach is to have a service configured with `@Cacheable` methods which return the relevant information (probably best not to cache the actual entity, but caching information in the entity is fine).  You can evict/update the cache at whatever frequency or in response to whatever events in the app that you like.

https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache/3.0.2/index.html